# "Don't keep activities" - when app is restored the fragment is visible only for a second

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have an app that uses fragments. If I enable "dont keep activities", then enter the activity and enter the fragment, then minimize with the Home button and reopen the app the following behavior occurs - the app restores on the open fragment for about half a second, and immediately after that the fragment closes and the main activity for the application shows.

Do I need to perform some sort of restore state for the fragment manager for cases like this? Also, why is the fragment showing at all for half a second and then closing?

code for the MainActivity:

```
myFragment = (MyFragment) MyFragment.create(id);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,     R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                //.hide(getMainFragment())
                .add(R.id.content, MyFragment.create(id), MY_FRAGMENT_TAG)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
        setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Unless you edit your question and post minimal code to reproduce the behaviour it's unlikely anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: thanks. The only problem is which code to post.. both activities (main+fragment) are very long and its not clear to me what would be relevant. I was wondering if this was a general "known issue" with using "dont keep activities" involving fragments - rather than something specific to my case

Answer (score 11, accepted):

fragment lifecycle behaves differently when you have used "dont keep activities" enabled.

Normal flow of activity with fragment

```
MainActivity onCreate
          Fragment onAttach
          Fragment onCreate
          Fragment onCreateView
          Fragment onViewCreated
          Fragment onActivityCreated 
MainActivity onStart
          Fragment onStart
```

But when you have enabled "dont keep activities" and pressed home button then the lifecycle behaves differently as

```
   Fragment onAttach
          Fragment onCreate
MainActivity onCreate
          Fragment onCreateView
          Fragment onViewCreated
          Fragment onActivityCreated
MainActivity onStart
          Fragment onStart
```

So, purely depends upon the logic you have written.

Post your MainActivity and Fragment code. So that any one can help.

Check this post [Fragment Lifecycle wrt Activity](http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.in/2014/05/fragment-lifecycle-with-respect-to-its.html)